# Monodromy theorem in Princeton lectures in analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, terminology

I am very curious to know if what is called the "Monodromy Theorem" or "Riemann Monodromy Theorem" is also known by some other name.

For all my complex analysis requirements I have always fallen back on the book by Elias Stein and Rami Shakarchi and it has never failed me. I find its presentation just too good. But quite mysteriously I am unable to locate in it this particular theory which otherwise is present in almost every other book on complex analysis like that by Raghavan Narsimhan, Kunihiko Kodaira, Aflfors etc.

Can anyone kindly help point out if that book has that in some other name or in some different disguise?

Comment: It's been a while since I looked at that book, so I may have just forgotten it. But I don't think it is in Stein-Shakarchi. The discussion of analytic continuations in that book is a bit weak.

Comment: Have you read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monodromy_theorem?